# Node is installed during provisioning on vagrant but disappears upon connecting to ssh

Tags: node.js, vagrant, nvm, ubuntu-13.04

I am really getting sick of this and I don't know what is wrong. I am using **Vagrant 1.7.2** , **Ubuntu 13.04** , **Virtual Box 4.3 12 r93733**

My host machine is **Windows 8.1**

Here is my node bootstrap script found on my bootstrap.sh

```
echo "--- Installing Node.js ---"
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.16.1/install.sh | bash
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install 0.12
nvm use 0.12
sudo cp ~/.nvm/versions/nodejs/v0.12/bin/node /bin/node

echo "--- Install node app dependencies --"
cd /var/www/html/node
npm install express
npm install youtube-audio-stream
```

During provisioning I could see that node is installed correctly . I could see the **Now using node v0.12** . I could also see that the **npm install**'s are successful

However when I connect using **vagrant ssh** . I get **No command 'nvm' found** . And **The program 'node' can be found in the following packages:** . I also checked **~/.nvm/** directory, it is not existing.

It becomes even weirder. So while I'm at ssh, I rerun the script again. Then nvm is now correctly installed and I could use node.

Comment: This might be a permissions issue with your SSH user

Comment: If that is the case, why is the nvm directory gone? And when I try to execute the same script on ssh , it still works?

Comment: Perhaps because the SSH user doesn't have access to the nvm directory created by a different user

Comment: I'm wondering did you get this figured out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I came up with

```
echo "--- Installing Node.js ---"
git clone https://github.com/creationix/nvm.git /home/vagrant/.nvm && cd /home/vagrant/.nvm && git checkout `git describe --abbrev=0 --tags`
source /home/vagrant/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm install 0.12
nvm use 0.12
n=$(which node);n=${n%/bin/node}; chmod -R 755 $n/bin/*; sudo cp -r $n/{bin,lib,share} /usr/local
```